# View not taking up equal space in height with flex in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am trying to get two views to take up **equal space in height** with Flex but it does not seem to work as intended. Maybe i am doing something wrong or misunderstood the system of Flex?

As you can see below the text does not take up the entire height of the View but still it creates space below the text.

If i remove the text element and set a static width it works as intended.

**Edit1:** When placing the code outside the parent ScrollView it works as intended. It seems that a parent ScrollView is causing this with flexGrow 1.

**Edit2:** I created a **snack** to reproduce the problem. It **works in web** version but **not in android**.

[Link to snack](https://snack.expo.dev/cB9Tolw_u)

**Code:**

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'column',flex:1,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'#FFF'}}>
      <View style={{flex:1,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'yellow'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:12,color:'#FFF',borderColor:'green',borderWidth:1}}>test text goes here</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'yellow'}}>
      </View>  
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

**Result below:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you expected this,[image] kind of view.

Just replace your view with this code below.I think this will work for you.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000' }}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#FFF' }}>
                    <View style={{height:'50%',flexDirection: 'column', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'yellow' }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 80, color: '#fff', borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 1 }}>test text goes here</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ height:'50%', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'yellow' }}>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

Comment: Not really. I want the yellow border to be equal in height and not affected by the text element. Your solution give the same behavior in the snack aswell.

Comment: Then you should try height:'50%' instance of flex: 1

Comment: now you should try the code i given before, i edited code with write one. check.

Comment: If you want to show Long text then use Text component inside of Scrollview component or use ellipsizeMode='tail' inside text component to show .... after fill screen

Comment: Wow! Sometimes the most simple solutions make it work :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#FFF",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  }}
>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "yellow" }}>
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 12,
        color: "#FFF",
        borderColor: "green",
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}
    >
      test text goes here
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "yellow" }}></View>
</View>;
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but same behavior im afraid :(

Comment: One possible solution:

Give height to Views just like: <View style={{flex:1,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'yellow', height: 100}}>

Comment: That is a solution but not an alternative as the content is dynamic

Comment: I created a snack to reproduce the problem